# How do I include asset files with parcel js?

Tags: javascript, assets, parcel, parceljs

I have a folder of dynamically loaded asset files I want to include in my parcel output directory. How can I include unreferenced static asset files like `.json, .jpeg, .txt, .etc` with my `parcel build` command?

Answer (score 11):

With Parcel v2 there's a different plugin: https://github.com/elwin013/parcel-reporter-static-files-copy

```
yarn add parcel-reporter-static-files-copy --dev
```

then you need to create `.parcelrc` or add to the following to it. (Note: `"..."` is literal not something you need to fill in):

```
{
  "extends": ["@parcel/config-default"],
  "reporters":  ["...", "parcel-reporter-static-files-copy"]
}
```

now any files (and sub-directories) in a directory named `static` will be automatically copied to the website (typically your `dist` folder) when you do the regular parcel build.

Comment: This plugin seems to break the local dev server though, at least when using the `-p` option. I saw it successfully copy the files over but my local site stopped responding and removing the plugin fixed that.

Comment: The plugin broke the development server, but the fault is mine, I am too lazy to read that the "..." from the answer is literal.

Comment: Note this may require to install config-default, so run `npm install @parcel/config-default`

Comment: while this works, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a separate dependency. At that point, a basic `cp` command or a copy library would be simpler/more up to date

Answer (score 5):

The best way to handle this is having control of the code. `npm` already provides the tools needed for this job. In the `package.json`, when running commands with `&&`, the first command will run, and if it does finish without any error, the second command will also be executed. Running `&`, however, will run each command in the background independently, regardless of what happens to the other command.
In other words:

- Use `&&` for sequential execution.
- Use `&` for parallel execution.

For example:

```
project/
|dist/
    |...
|src/
    |assets/
        |text.txt
        |memos.txt
        |info.ini
    |css/
        |style.css
    |img/
        |a.png
        |b.jpg
        |c.jpeg
    |data.json
    |not-to-copy.json
    |not-to-copy.conf
    |index.js
    |index.html
|package.json
```

If you have a project structure like this add, some scripts to the `package.json`

```json
{
    ...
    "source": "src/index.html",
    "scripts": {
        "clean-dist": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist",
        "copy-img": "cp -vR ./src/img ./dist",
        "copy-data": "cp -r src/data.json dist",
        "copy-assets": "cp -r src/assets/* dist",
        "copy-files": "npm run copy-img & npm run copy-assets & npm run copy-data",
        "init": "npm run clean-dist && npm run copy-files",
        "start": "npm run init && parcel",
        "build": "npm run init && parcel build"
    },
    ...
}
```

This configuration will sequentially run `clean-dist` and `copy-files`. The former will delete the `dist` directory and make the directory again. Then `copy-files` will copy `src/img -> dist/img`, `src/assets/* -> dist/*` and `src/data.json -> dist/data.json` in parallel. Finally, parcel will be executed.

Comment: so far, this has been a workaround, but was hoping for something built into parcel itself

Answer (score 4):

Note: This answer is for Parcel v1

There is a parcel plugin for that:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-static-files-copy

Install it:

```
yarn add parcel-plugin-static-files-copy --dev
```

Or

```
npm install -D parcel-plugin-static-files-copy
```

Then, in `package.json`, add:

```
"staticFiles": {
   "staticPath": ["path/to/a/staticFolder"]
}
```

It should copy your files to the public folder.

Stay safe!

Comment: so there's no native way to do this without a plugin?

Comment: No, It's still an open issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your package.json scripts to copy the files after the build has executed. This is how I had a .htaccess file to the `dist` folder:

```
"build": "rm -rf dist && parcel build src/index.html -d dist --public-url ./ '.' cp src/.htaccess dist"
```

Comment: While this works, I was hoping for parcel to do this as part of the build.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree.

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build-img && parcel",
    "build-img": "parcel build assets/* --no-cache"
  }
}
```