# Dynamic insertion of images into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to create a simple weather app. It gets an API response where weather description is represented by some string, for eg: `"clear sky"`. I've created a JS object which maps those strings to the corresponding icon file paths which are in `src/assets/images` folder:

```js
const weatherIcons = {
  // ...
  "Heavy_Rain": "../assets/images/icons8-heavy-rain-96.png",
  // ...
}
```

I'm trying to dynamically display that icon in my component:

```html
<img className="img-fluid" src={require(weatherIcons.Heavy_Rain)} />
```

And I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module '../assets/images/icons8-heavy-rain-96.png'

But it works perfectly if I use the string directly as a `require` argument:

```html
<img className="img-fluid" src={require("../assets/images/icons8-heavy-rain-96.png")} />
```

I use Parcel instead of Webpack to bundle project files. And I didn't run Create React App, so I don't have Public folder in my project.

What do I do to have my icons displayed eventually?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening at runtime:

```
require(weatherIcons.Heavy_Rain)
```

This happens at compile:

```
require("../assets/images/icons8-heavy-rain-96.png")
```

So you will need a public folder for dynamic or some public link with the image.

If your homepage is set to "." and put the image in the public folder it should work.

Comment: How can I create public folder corresponding to /public url?

Comment: For parcel you can do as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713341/how-do-i-include-asset-files-with-parcel-js

Comment: Unfotunately, it only works out for final bundle build. Thanks anyway.